# php + cURL + TLS 1.2

Tags: php, ssl, curl, tls1.2

I'm using maxmind GEOIP precision online service to get information about visitor region/city. 
They are upgrading their protocol to TLS 1.2. I tried to change my code, but they told me that logs indicate that I'm still sending requests using TLS 1.0

```
$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://geoip.maxmind.com/geoip/v2.1/insights/178.166.46.246"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);


$result = curl_exec($ch);  
curl_close($ch);  
return $result;
```

Adding "CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2" doesn't seem to help.
What is that I may be missing here?

Comment: what's the value of CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2?

Comment: adding value 6 should do the job

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
```

This enforces the request to use TLS 1.2.

Comment: Please describe in your answer, what was the problem, and how will this snippet solve it, to help others understand this answer